# Unique variables inside foreach()

Tags: php, variables, foreach

Trying to create a variable with unique name for each `$item`.

To prevent error "Only variables can be passed by reference".

---

If there are 5 items in array `$items`, we should get 5 unique variables:

```
$item_name_1;
$item_name_2;
$item_name_3;
$item_name_4;
$item_name_5;
```

All of them should be empty.

**What is a true solution for this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically create variable names doing the following:

```
$item_name_{$count} = $whatever;
```

I must warn you though, this is absolutely bad style and I've never seen a good reason to use this. In almost every use case an array would be the better solution.

Comment: how to create an empty variable? without =

Comment: What's the point of an empty variable? You don't need to explicitly declare variables in PHP. Just use the variable when you assign something to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess that you can use $item_name_{$count} = "lorem ipsum"; for it

... But won't be better to use an array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, so this may be completely wrong. Anyway, if what you want is an array with empty values you can use this code:

```
<?php
$arr = array_fill(0, 3, '');
var_export($arr) // array ( 0 => '', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', )
?>
```

See [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) for more information.

If this is the wrong answer, please clarify what you mean. I may be able to help you.